# How can you use async apis with ndb hooks?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

I have some hooks in place, and I thought I could decorate them with @ndb.tasklet in order to use async apis inside the hooks.
e.g.

```
@classmethod
@ndb.tasklet
def _post_delete_hook(cls, key,future):
    yield do_something_async()
```

This *seemed* to work, but every now and then I see "suspended generator" error for the code inside those hooks.

Should I be using @ndb.synctasklet instead?

An example of error:

```
suspended generator _post_put_hook(data_field.py:112) raised TypeError(Expected Future, received <class 'google.appengine.api.apiproxy_stub_map.UserRPC'>: <google.appengine.api.apiproxy_stub_map.UserRPC object at 0x09AA00B0>)
```

The code causing the error occasionally was:

```
           t, d = yield (queue.add_async(task), queue.delete_tasks_async(taskqueue.Task(name=existing_task_name)))
```

Now that I've put @ndb.synctasklet it raises an actual exception.

Comment: Can you show such (complete) suspended generator errors? They *might* be unrelated...

Comment: @DanCornilescu thanks, updated.

Comment: I *think* the message may suggest an error encountered in creating a `Future` for an async op. You're trying to create 2 Futures at once in that yield - is it aways the case or is sometimes possible to only have one of them? Can you add checks to see if each future is created correctly? Shots in the dark mostly, I didn't play much with the tasklets so far.

Comment: @DanCornilescu thanks. I split them out into 2 separate yields now (not ideal). I haven't seen the error again. I think the error was being raised by delete_tasks_async. My main issue though is whether it's correct to decorate it as ndb.tasklet or ndb.synctasklet. ndb.tasklet seemed to high the error away

Comment: I'm not suggesting to use 2 `yield` ops, just assign each `*_async` call to a variable, check the vars and yield only the valid ones.

Comment: The `ndb.synctasklet` vs `ndb.tasklet` depends on how you're using it - if you need to wait for the result or not. From what I can gather it appears you don't need to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An ndb tasklet returns a future.  If calling the tasklet results in an exception, the exception will only be raised if the future's `get_result` method is called.

`ndb.synctasklet` automatically calls `get_result` on the futures yielded by tasklets, causing exceptions to be raised if they occurred, rather than just logged.

For the error that you are seeing, you may be able to fix it by converting the UserRPCs returned by the taskqueue async methods to tasklets.

This untested code is based on `ndb.context.urlfetch` ([link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/datastore-ndb-python/blob/master/ndb/context.py#L982)), which converts the `UserRPC` produced by `urlfetch.createRPC` into a `Future`.

```
  @ndb.tasklet
  def add_async(queue, **taskqueue_kwargs):
      rpc = queue.add_async(**taskqueue_kwargs)
      result = yield rpc
      raise ndb.Return(result)
```

You would need to create a tasklet for each async method that you want to use, or you could extend the taskqueue class and make the async methods tasklets.

Comment: isn't that just the same as result = yield queue.add_async()?  The taskqueue issue was secondary, the main concern was whether post_put_hooks/deletes/gets can be @nbd.tasklets or not.